# find a element with certain name in a js variable filled by a jquery query

Tags: jquery, find

I can search the dom with *.find('.dbfieldname')* to find all elements from the class dbname.
I also can save the result as an object in a variable like that: *myelems = .find(...*

But I can't search in my object for certain elements using `find()`. I tried the following:

```
my.find(*[name=versionnumber])
```

How can I do that right ?

Comment: This is missing so much information. What is `my` for starters?

Comment: my is a javascript array, which holds all the elements found by the following jquery query: my = $('input')

Answer (score 4):

Your logic is fine, `my` is already a jQuery object, so `my.find()` would normally work.

The problem is that `.find()` searches for childrens.  What you want is `my.filter('[name="' +versionnumber+ '"]');`

Comment: The following worked fine:

    my.filter('[name="' +versionnumber+ '"]');

But I'm not sure if my really is a object - I think it is an ordinary js array, because I can reach the elements by `my[index]`.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Actually, I'm not really sure how it's stored.  I'm going to ask SO if it's not already asked.  All I know is you can retrieve the HTML elements using my[index]; but if you wanted to retrieve them as jQuery objects, you can use my.eq(index).

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(my).find("*[name=versionnumber]")
```

Btw, better use `jQuery.find()` or `$.find()` rather than just `.find()`, it makes code at least more readable.

Comment: thanks, but this doesn't work as well. I tried:

jQuery(my).find("*")
jQuery(my).find("*[name=database]")
$(my).find("*[name=database]")

don't know why - I can get elements like that:
*my[0].name*
but then I would have to loop through all elements two times.

Comment: Well, what is "my"? It should be a jQuery object or DOM node. If it is some hand-made JS-object you cant use jQuery on it